# Specman e: Is there a way to print unit instance name?

Tags: specman, e

I've built a generic `agent` that will be instantiated several times in the environment:

```
unit agent_u {
    monitor : monitor_u is instance;
};
```

The monitor prints some messages, e.g.:

```
unit monitor_u {
    run() is also {
        message(LOW, "Hello monitor!");
    };
};
```

I would like to add to the monitor's messages which agent instance has printed them. For example, for environment:

```
extend sys {
    first_agent : agent_u is instance;
    second_agent : agent_u is instance;
};
```

the desirable output will be something like that:

```
first_agent: Hello monitor!
second_agent: Hello monitor!
```

I could not find anything related to instance name in the reflection API... Is there some way to print an instance name in e?

Thank you for your help

Comment: The `e_path()` method of a unit returns a string representing the full instance hierarchy of the unit. May not be what you require though.

Comment: It's cool - it does shows the instance name. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

printing with message() will already include the instance pointer, in your case something like:

```
[0] agent_u-@1: Hello monitor!
[0] agent_u-@2: Hello monitor!
```

you can distinguish by these @**NUM**.

or include "me.e_path()" in your message, which will give the full instance path:

```
     message(LOW, me.e_path(), ": Hello monitor!");

[0] agent_u-@1: sys.first_agent.monitor: Hello monitor! 
[0] agent_u-@2: sys.second_agent.monitor: Hello monitor!
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you refer to by "the instance name", but there are several points to be aware of.

There is the predefined `e_path()` method of `any_unit`.

There is a unique identifier for struct and unit instances, consisting of the type name and a unique number, which is returned by `to_string()` method. This unique identifier is already printed as part of a message.

Moreover, you can use the predefined hook method `create_formatted_message()`, preferably together with defining your own new `message_format`, to customize how messages are printed. For example, you might append the result of `e_path()` to the formatted message string, if you wish it to automatically appear in all messages.

You can also use the `short_name()` hook to provide your own symbolic names to units, and those will appear in messages instead of the result of `to_string()`.

In principle, you can also override `to_string()` itself, but that would have more effects than just messages printout.